# conditional entropies for identical distributions

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let me say I have two distributions $X$ and $Y$ which are identical, but they are not independent. 
Now if were to calculate the conditional entropies $H(X|Y)$ and $H(Y|X)$. Is calculating one joint entropy is enough for me ?

Regards,
phani tej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our definition of conditional entropy:

$$
H(Y|X) = \sum_{x}p_{X}(x)H(Y|X=x) = -\mathbb{E}[\text{log}p(Y|X)]
$$

We know the chain rule which states that:
$$
H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y|X) = H(Y) + H(X|Y)
$$

so 
$$
H(Y|X) - H(X|Y) = H(Y) - H(X) = 0 
$$
by the fact that X and Y have the same distribution. Of course this is clear from the symmetry.

Comment: Very sleek proof!